# Software packaging for RedHat similar to Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, rhel, package-management

I'm currently helping a professor who is having trouble installing a particular software onto the school's server which runs on Red Hat/Fedora. The professor thinks that the software was packaged for Ubuntu which distributes files together rather than into multiple folders which apparently is what Red Hat/Fedora does (correct me if I'm wrong!).

Is there a way to distribute software on Red Hat/Fedora in a similar fashion as Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing things called tar-balls (when referring to multiple folders), with regular installation packages (files ending in `.deb` on Debian/Ubuntu and in `.rpm` on Red Hat/Fedora/SuSE).

The former is "only" a, often compressed, directory structure with some instruction (in the form of scripts, Makefiles, configuration files) to get the files installed to the right directories on your system after unpacking. This has the disadvantage that it is often difficult to reverse such an installation.

Installation packages (`.deb`, `.rpm`) have, broadly speaking, additional information on where what files are installed, so they can be deinstalled (there are also post- an pre-install and deinstall scripts for additional actions etc.).

The packagings can proceed directly from source, but is often based on the "more primitive" tar balls. There are often similarities that for a large subset of packages in one form, they can be converted to the other using the program [`alien`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_%28software%29)